# Nginx exact match is not working with =

Tags: nginx

Currently, I am using the below configuration in NGINX and the exact match is not working for me. Could someone help me?

```
 location = /graphql {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
 };

 location  / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
 };
```

When I am sending the request with /graphql-tutorials/something, the Nginx is routing this to port 3000 but I am expecting this to reach 4000?

I want only when users enter /graphql then it should listen to 3000 else in any other case it should reach 4000

Regards

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and ensure that the `location` blocks appear as in your question.

Comment: Yes @AlexeyTen , I had restarted nginx before posting this question

Comment: Yes @RichardSmith, I tried nginx -T and the configuration looks fine

Comment: Since you checked the configuration, I assume it is fully correct. But still, are you willing to post the whole configuration for us to check?